# UITableView - SelectedBackgroundView not working in iOS7 with Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using UITableVeiw with static cells in iOS7. The table view looked like this before I converted my storyboard to use autolayouts.

[image]

I am using the "background view" property and the "selectedBackgroundView" property of the tableviewcell to set backgrounds like so:

[image]

After enabling auto-layout though in the storyboard, the layout goes bonkers and this is what I am left with:

[image]

I don't have any auto-layout issues that are presented to me. Just that I am not seeing the foreground and background anymore with auto-Layouts.

Any help?

Comment: Try re-arranging the views. That should help.

Comment: ^What's your reasoning behind that suggestion? The DefaultBackgroundView and SelectedBackGroundView do not follow the view hierarchy because they are not in them. 

I still tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the auto-layout was creating problems for me. I added the backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView programmatically and it works.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIView *selectedView =[UIView new];
    selectedView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.604 green:0.812 blue:0.059 alpha:1.000];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView;
    UIView *defaultView =[UIView new];
    defaultView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.396 green:0.404 blue:0.404 alpha:1.000];
    cell.backgroundView = defaultView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be fixed in `Storyboard` but... the "solution" is totally stupid :D. If add width and height constraint to `selectedBackgroundView` it will works. This solution isn't good for me, but seems like it works :)

P.S. The way with adding `selectedBackgroundView` programmatically is work for me too.