# Background view on UITableViewCell hugs content when using slicing xcassets

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have some very simple UITableViewCells, there is just one one-line UILabel and UIImageView (white arrow). UILabel is anchored to it's parent (content view) top/bottom, the arrow is irrelevant now. When I try to set background view to UIImageView that is loading stretchable image from xcassets, this image view hugs the label which is sizeToFit'ed automatically for some reason.

I have set constraints on both label and background view to anchor them to top/bottom of content view, but they still get small.

The cell's height is 50pt, the label is about 20pt so the difference is quite visible.

Any idea what should I do to have background view fill entire content view?

**EDIT:**

In following image, you can see 2 cells, one of them in selected state. The bottom cell has both background view and selected background view set. Background view (black one) has no vertical slicing, it's simply image with 50pt height, the Selected background view (the red one) has slicing enabled and it hugs the label vertically.

What I want to achieve is to have slicing enabled for both background and selected background view and having it behave like the non-sliced background view on the image, that is filling entire content view of the cell

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

screenshot of cell layout and constraints set on the imageview that is set as background view on cell

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain more clear what you want ?

Comment: I am not sure I can :) I will upload an image that should help

Comment: If you want to fill it, design it in storyboard itself.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It is designed in storyboard, there are two ImageViews, both have constraints set to fill the content view completely, see my second edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found related question with answer that helped, so this might be a duplicate.

[UITableView - SelectedBackgroundView not working in iOS7 with Auto-Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215150/uitableview-selectedbackgroundview-not-working-in-ios7-with-auto-layout)

Solution is to create those background view programatically as there is probably yet another bug in interface builder that is screwing this up.